# How to automate the generation of schema (SQL server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, integration

I am beginning a big data project and I eventually will have a lot of different databases that I need to put into a consistent schema in my data warehouse as they become available.  I am trying to find a tool to automate the reading of an incoming dataset's schema so we can compare it to the data warehouse's schema.

Ideally, the tool would allow me to edit the schema in the tool as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a way to write a database migration. There's a lot of tools out there. You could try Liquibase, DbUp, or Flyway. You can write migrations/scripts to create the schema you need, version control the scripts, and allow the tool to determine if they should be executed on your target database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without needing a tool, just look at the information_schema schema in the databases. You can write your own scripts that report on differences, or you can use a diff tool on reports you run against information_schema.tables etc.

Doing it this way will give you control over exactly what you want to do. If not, use a migration tool as @Phil_Busch suggested.